# Why does adding an empty string fix my TextView.setText()?

Tags: android

i'm trying to make a simple app which adds 3 in display,just got confused in one part this doesn't work in my phone and showing some error.

```
public void addThreeToTeamA(View view) {
        ScoreOfTeamA = ScoreOfTeamA + 3;
        displayScore(ScoreOfTeamA);
  }

  public void displayScore(int score){
     TextView text = findViewById(R.id.display_TeamA_score);
  text.setText(score);
```

**And this works perfectly fine**

```
public void addThreeToTeamA(View view) {
            ScoreOfTeamA = ScoreOfTeamA + 3;
            displayScore(ScoreOfTeamA);
      }

      public void displayScore(int score){
         TextView text = findViewById(R.id.display_TeamA_score);
      text.setText("" + score);
```

**What is "" doing in the last line to make app work??**

**This is the xml file**

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/display_TeamA_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/_0"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

 <Button
            android:onClick="addThreeToTeamA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/AddThree"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
```

*This is not full code its just important parts.*

Comment: I added an answer assuming the error you get is a nullpointer. If it´s not, show us the logcat with the exception you get - maybe setText with int value is not working, the log is needed to say for sure what it happening.

Comment: TextView has a method which accepts an string resource id (integer), but you are trying to pass some integer as parameter but it's not a valid resource identifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`score` is of type `int`. The `setText` method that you want to use expects something of type `char[]`, i.e, a string. Note that another `setText` method does expect an integer, which is used to find a resource through its ID. This is why you don't get an error when using `setText(score)`.

Knowing this:

- On `text.setText(score);`, if you convert `score` to a string, it will work (for instance, using `Integer.toString(score)`).
- On `text.setText("" + score);`, you already have the `""` string, and Java understands that you're trying to append an integer to a string, so it returns a string. This version, however, is not efficient, since everytime you concatenate something to a string, you're creating a new string (this is why people use `StringBuilder`).

Long story short, just convert `score` to a string.

Answer (score 4):

You're using two different versions of `setText()`:

1. The one taking an int: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widgetTextView.html#setText(int)
2. The one taking a CharSequence (e.g. a String): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)

The first one takes a *resource id*. The TextView will try to load that resource as a string. Since you're supplying an arbitrary int, you're probably getting a "Resource Not Found" exception.

The second one takes a CharSequence, and will simply display that exact text.

Changing the argument to `"" + score` will create a string containing the appropriate characters to display the `score` value.