# Retrieving info from an object

Tags: android, textview

I'm using a Github file to manage my In-app Products. I want to retrieve the price of one product and I'm suppose to follow the instructions below to do so:

To query listing price and a description of your product / subscription listed in Google Play use these methods:

bp.getPurchaseListingDetails("PRODUCT ID");
As a result you will get a SkuDetails object with the following info included:

```
public final String currency;
public final Double priceValue;
public final String priceText;
```

I'm trying to set a TextView's text to the the price value of the product like so:

```
textView.setText();
```

Anyone know how I can set the text as the price value kept in priveValue

Comment: textView.setText(priceValue+" ");

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447851/why-does-adding-an-empty-string-fix-my-textview-settext/52447993#52447993

Comment: So I have to declare them or how do I retrieve the value?